# using lambda in a for loop with zip()

Tags: python

Hello guys I've been playing today a bit with python and got a bit confused while using the lambda fucntion. 
My original intention was to subtract the value of each element in a vector with the values form a second vector and introduce all the results in a 3rd vector. Went like this:

```
v1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
v2 =[7,2 ,7 ,6]
v3=[x-y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]
```

then I though to calculate using the same structure the absolute value using a lambda function and I tried this:

```
v1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
v2 =[7,2 ,7 ,6]
[lambda x,y: x-y if x>y else y-x for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]
```

this only gives memory locations I think. and I don't know why , wehre I did wrong?

Comment: This should only give you a list with one element, being a lambda function object, right?

Comment: @NiklasR: No.  It gives a list with 4 items, each being a lambda function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you a bunch of `lambda` functions.  All you did there is define the function, but you never call it.  Do this instead:

```
[(lambda x,y: x-y if x>y else y-x)(x,y) for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]
```

You really don't need a function, though.  Just do it like this:

```
[(x-y if x>y else y-x) for x,y in zip(v1,v2)]
```

Comment: Ohh thx it works :D thx a lot :) also for the super quick answer .

Comment: or use `abs(x-y)` instead of the `if.. else..`

Comment: @chapelo: Yeah, definitely.  I didn't really pay much attention to what the `lambda` function did.

Comment: @WiuWiti: But `lambdas` do have their place: whenever you have a short definition for a function, you can avoid the `def ...` with a lambda. They are specially usefull when passing functions to arguments that expect functions, like `max` or `sort` that could expect a sort by function.

Comment: Yes I know but I wanted to try to put an if statement in a lambda to try to see how it looks(if that makes sense) thank you all for the replies. Now I understand what I did wrong.